# Why does getent default to .station if no TLD is specified?

Tags: linux, dns, nsswitch, mdns, getent

With my current setup, I have a `dnsmasq` instance operating on my home server (Void Linux) and 3 GNU/Linux devices that use it as default dns (1 Manjaro, 1 Arch, 1 Linux Mint 20.1).

Due to seemingly unrelated issues, I was testing the mdns name resolution with `getent`, and I noticed, both by looking at `dnsmasq` logs and running `strace getent`, that `getent` would automatically append the `.station` Top Level Domain if the domain wasn't already specified.

`getent hosts home-server` results in

```
dnsmasq[24671]: query[AAAA] home-server.station from 192.168.0.6
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 9.9.9.9
dnsmasq[24671]: query[AAAA] home-server.station from 192.168.0.6
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 9.9.9.9
dnsmasq[24671]: query[AAAA] home-server.station from 192.168.0.6
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 9.9.9.9
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 95.216.24.230
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 89.233.43.71
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 78.46.244.143
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 146.255.56.98
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 78.46.244.143
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 146.255.56.98
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 78.46.244.143
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 146.255.56.98
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 45.90.57.121
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 80.67.169.40
dnsmasq[24671]: forwarded home-server.station to 104.244.78.231
dnsmasq[24671]: reply home-server.station is NXDOMAIN
dnsmasq[24671]: query[AAAA] home-server from 192.168.0.6
```

On the dnsmasq log and

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
setsockopt(4, SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR, [1], 4) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.100")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(4, "\2\17\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\vhome-server\7station"..., 37, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 3
```

Calling `getent` with `strace`.

I wasn't able to find any information regarding the `.station` TLD.

Does anyone know why does `getent` have this default behavior, and where does the `.station` come from?

My `/etc/nsswitch.conf` `hosts` line on Manjaro

```
hosts: files mymachines mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve dns mdns4 myhostname
```

On Mint

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

Comment: Is `.station` the domain name that your DHCP server has given you?

Comment: I'm using a Vodafone Power Station that by default responds at the `http://vodafone.station/` name. However I don't understand how it would influence `getent`'s behavior.
I'm not sure how to check if it gave my devices names

Comment: Because `mdns4_minimal` provides a minimal zeroconf (aka Rendezvous, aka Bonjour) lookup service for nsswitch.   Your vodafone power station is probably publishing it to the local LAN.    Zeroconf, of course, is short-hand for "Screw up my network with semi-random, unreliable, undiagnosable, unfixable garbage".  Thanks, Apple.  And avahi.  And nss-mdns.

Comment: Try removing `mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]` and `mdns4` from the hosts entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: @cas Still happens even without `mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getent hosts` does what the `hosts` line of `nsswitch.conf` tells it to do. The `strace` indicates it's sending a unicast DNS query to 192.168.0.100.

You have two hostname resolution services that could use unicast DNS: `resolve` and `dns`. One or both of these have apparently been configured, probably by your DHCP client, to use `station` as your DNS default domain.

For `resolve`, run `resolvectl status`. For `dns`, run `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. This should tell you which of the DNS resolution services has the `station` domain configured.

(Unless `resolve` is configured to not use regular DNS, the use of both `resolve` and `dns` together is a bit of a belt-and-suspenders configuration: normally you would need only one or the other.)

If you are using NetworkManager to configure your network interfaces and are using DHCP, you might look at the newest `*.lease` file (or equivalent; this may depend on which DHCP client NetworkManager is configured to use) in `/var/lib/NetworkManager` to see which DHCP server actually gave you the IP address and which additional DHCP options came along with it.

Another way to see the DHCP options given by the DHCP server would be to run `nmcli c show` to list the configured connections, find the name of the active connection, and then use `nmcli c show <name of active connection> | grep DHCP..OPTION`.

Since Vodafone Power Station is your router, it most likely also acts as a DHCP server for your home network. `.station` is probably just its factory default setting for the  DNS domain, and it propagates that setting to all its DHCP clients. It can probably be changed from the router's settings.

Comment: Yup, the power station configured NetworkManager to use the `.station` domain name, which is then used by the `dns` option in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Due to the unrelated issue, I ended up checking `/etc/resolv.conf`, which is created by `NetworkManager` on all the distros I use as clients.

According to @Kusalananda 's suggestion, it seems that the Vodafone Power Station causes network manger to add the `search station` option to the file and it's ip address as a DNS server; removing such line causes the `http://vodafone.station` name resolution to fail on Firefox (which is weird in itself, because the name is still resolved by the station's DNS)